# How to efficiently remove the first few chars of a row in text file?

Tags: text, batch-file, formatting, command

Example of 2 rows in text file (abc.txt):

```
    PMIP_TSD_2012120323.csv:03/12/2012,22:51:53,CAU TACS,TS,PPT4I_TS22,   AJAY,595959,P,Legal Exit,(6 0) AJAY,G1234567M,SERVICES P L,8401352W,  

    PMIP_TSD_2012111300.csv:12/11/2012,23:20:13,CAU TACS,TS,PPT4O_TS32,ARUMUGAM,620466,P,Legal Exit,(5 0) ARUMUGAM,G686W,SUPERSONIC SERVICES P L,1982W,
```

I would like every row to start with the date instead of the csv file name. Meaning removing the PMIP......csv: for every row. How can i do this using batch file? I have hundreds of rows, i do not wish to do it manually. My file name is abc.txt and it is located in D:\Int\ KGX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Batch file do that:

```
@echo off
cd /D "D:\Int\KGX"
(for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in (abc.txt) do (
   echo %%b
)) > abc-NEW.txt
```

Comment: @10e5x: Ops, one parentheses missed! Please, copy the Batch file again and test it.

Answer (score 1):

`perl -npi -e 's/[^:]+://' /tmp/abc.txt` yields:

```
03/12/2012,22:51:53,CAU TACS,TS,PPT4I_TS22,   AJAY,595959,P,Legal Exit,(6 0) AJAY,G1234567M,SERVICES P L,8401352W,  
12/11/2012,23:20:13,CAU TACS,TS,PPT4O_TS32,ARUMUGAM,620466,P,Legal Exit,(5 0) ARUMUGAM,G686W,SUPERSONIC SERVICES P L,1982W,
```

from your data. Hope that helps...

Comment: so i just put perl -npi -e 's/[^:]+://' /tmp/abc.txt yields: into a text file and save it as batch and run. I nv seen this kind of command before.

Comment: It replaces it inline, so you just run it from command line, assuming you're working with Unix

Answer (score 1):

I can give you my thoughts about the problem

We can use C++ or Java to solve this problem

1. Open the file
2. In a loop we get the row in a String variable
3. use SubString (or some kind of similar functions or utilities) to specify the first index number (in our case 23)
4. Store the sub string in a new file
5. finish the loop

The new file is what you want, and hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, if there are VS or any SDK in this com, i would have done that long ago, too bad this is a Dino with no such program and i am very weak in batch cmds. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a in (abc.txt) do (
echo !date!:%%b >>new.txt
)
del abc.txt /f /q
ren new.txt abc.txt
```